# Converting corpus to dataframe returns NA's

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

I am trying to convert my corpus back to a dataframe but it returns only NA's. Please Help

Code:

```
library(wordcloud)
df <- data.frame(Description = c("I like this service very much"," this is worth it so much"))

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$Description))

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords('english')))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)

#a <- as.data.frame(corpus)

dataframe<-data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(corpus, `[`, "content")), 
                      stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Expected Output:

dataframe

```
'like servic much'
'worth much'
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code worked for me:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(text = sapply(corpus, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
              text
1 like servic much
2       worth much
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me too.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(text = sapply(corpus, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(Description = c("I like to travel. It expands my outlook. I have visited 12 National Parks."))
```

Output:

```
like travel expand outlook visit 12 nation park
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).